# In the aquation of cis-platin, why are the chloride ligands, and not ammonia, replaced with water, despite chloride's larger trans effect?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

https://doi.org/10.1021/ic000847w

In this paper, the aquation of cisplatin is examined. When used to treat cancer, the chlorides are substituted with water molecules, which seems to go against the trans rule discussed in my inorganic textbook. Supposedly ligands trans to chloride are more easily replaced than those trans to ammonia.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia page on the Spectrochemical series. I think it probably has to do with that.